# Adding code to my store

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to change the way the prices of my products are displayed in the `QuickViewContent` panel, instead of displaying `ProductPrice`, I want to display `PriceFrom - PriceUpTo`, indicating the price of the lowest price option and the price of the highest price option. Obviously, I will need to access global variables, do some code on them hen display the result.

My problem is that I'm new to BigCommerce, and I don't know:

1. Where I create those variables, and how do I know the names of the global variables I need.
2. Where I write the code and save it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you try to add fastcartcontent file?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj I don't really know what that is.

Comment: login to your admin end and them storefront end my themes edit html/css then find the file name fastcartcontent this is the file of QuickViewContent you can make changes here.